# How to find $P(Y \le X)$ without a joint probability distribution but both functions are known?

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, continuous-data

This was for homework, but the question has since been replaced by another question for some reason. Anyway:

$F_X(x)=\frac{1}{8}x^3,  0\le x \le 2$

$Y=\sqrt{X}$

Find $P(Y\le X)$

This is what is given. From there I went:

$f_X(x)=\frac{3}{8}x^2, 0\le x \le 2$

Using transformations, I obtained:

$f_Y(y)=\frac{3}{4}y^6, 0\le y \le \sqrt{2}$

From there I have no clue what to do. Normally I'd go

$\int^{2}_{0}\int^x_0f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx$

but there is no $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. If they were independent, I could multiply $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, I didn't know how I would show that.

Comment: $\sqrt{X}\lt X$ just means $X>1.$

Comment: Is that really it? Huh.